# Is the limit of an increasing sequence of continuous functions continuous in the extended real line

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions where $f_n:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and also $f_{n-1}(\theta)\leq f_n(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Then we can define $f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}\cup\infty$ as $f(\theta)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(\theta)$. Does it hold that the function $f$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]?$.
The topology on  $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\cup\infty$ is the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Thanks in advance any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}\right)^{1/n}=\begin{cases}2&\text{if }0<x\le2\pi\\ 1&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$